# Where did i go wrong with I/O with binary files in C?

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I need to encrypt a sentence using the Caesar cipher (its not done yet need to check for `xyz` and `XYZ` also), open a binary file and write the encrypted code there. The first argument should be the name of the binary file and choose if i want to add a sentence or show it, also if i input '#' as the first argument it prompts me to input the name of the binary file from which to read the code. It should go like this:

```
./a.out CODE.DAT >> A >> Kekli kek >> S >> Nhnol nhn >> E.
```

Now when I do this:

```
./a.out '#' >> CODE.DAT
```

It gives me the correct string up until the last character. Something like

```
Nhnol nhM�b�U"
```

Also if there are any bad habits in my code or any suggestions to write cleaner and better code I would be really happy if you would point it out.

Main function:

```c
int main(int argument_count, char **argument_vector) {
    if ((**(argument_vector + 1)) == '#') {
        FILE *stream;
        printf("Name of file: \n");
        char stream_name[15];
        scanf("%s", stream_name);
        if ((stream = fopen(stream_name, "rb")) != NULL) {
            char string[50];
            fread(string, sizeof(char *), 1, stream);
            printf("%s\n", string);
            fclose(stream);
        }
    } else
    if (argument_count == 2) {
        char character;
        do {
            printf("ADD [A], SHOW [S], END [E]\n");
            scanf("\n%c", &character);
            if (character == 'A') {
                FILE *stream;
                char string[50];
                read(string);
                code(string);
                if ((stream = fopen(*(argument_vector + 1), "wb")) != NULL) {
                    fwrite(string, sizeof(char *), 1, stream);
                    fclose(stream);
                }
            } else
            if (character == 'S') {
                FILE *stream;
                if ((stream = fopen(*(argument_vector + 1), "rb")) != NULL) {
                    char string[50];
                    fread(string, sizeof(char *), 1, stream);
                    printf("%s\n", string);
                    fclose(stream);
                }
            }
        } while (character != 'E');
    } else
        return printf("Error"), 1;
}
```

Code function:

```c
void code(char *string) {
    int i = 0;
    for(; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if ((int)string[i] == 32)
            string[i] = ' ';
        else
            string[i] += 3;
    }
    string[i + 1] = '\0';
}
```

Read function:

```c
void read(char *string) {
    printf("Input string: \n");
    scanf("\n%[^\n]%*c", string);
}
```

Comment: Everyone calls the arguments to main `argc` and `argv`. Don't make up your own names, it's just confusing for anyone reading your code.

Comment: And use ordinary array access syntax: `(** (argument_vector + 1))` should be `argv[1][0]`

Comment: File names can be longer than 14 characters. Avoid using arbitrary length buffers. You use `printf` on a buffer you read using `fread`. That is not guaranteed to be `'\0'` terminated. The `fread` function reads like 8 bytes at a time, which makes no sense at all. But if you just `fwrite` the buffer to `stdout` and don't forget to *use the return value* of `fread`, it should work.

Comment: `return printf("Error"), 1;` don't do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
        char string[50];
        fread(string, sizeof(char *), 1, stream);
        printf("%s\n", string);
```

`fread()` reads binary data, so it doesn't add a null terminator.

Also, `sizeof(char *)` is wrong. You're reading a string, not a pointer. But `fread()` is intended for reading fixed-size data. If you want to read a variable-sized string, you should specify `1` as the size of the object, and up to `49` objects (you need to allow room for the null terminator). `fread` returns the number of objects that it successfully read, use that to determine where to add the null byte.

```
        char string[50];
        size_t n = fread(string, 1, 49, stream);
        if (n > 0) {
            string[n] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", string);
        }
```

Comment: You might also mention that `sizeof(char *)` is irrelevant to read a string from the file.

Comment: Oops, I read that as `sizeof(char)`. `fread()` seems to be all wrong for this.

Comment: @Barmar The last character of my string wasn't being printed out with this code and i played around and you should edit it to string[n+1] = '\0'. This works. Thanks !

Comment: @MarkoMajstorovic No, because array indexes are zero-based. If you read 10 characters, they go in indexes `0` through `9`, and the null goes in `string[10]`.

Comment: @Barmar When i go with string[n] the last character of the string doesn't get printed, the string[n + 1] works well i don't know why, but if you have some free time could you see it for yourself. There isn't any extra code to this.

Comment: How long is the string in the file? `string[50]` is only enough room for 49 characters.

Comment: How long is your string? 50 bytes?

Comment: @MarkoMajstorovic You have to remember to leave room for the null terminator in C strings.

Comment: No, its 9 characters long + '\0' >> Kekli kek, it should output Nhnol nhn, but it swallows the last character and i get an output like Nhnol nh. I really don't know why does it do that.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I put `Kekli kek` in my file, and my `printf(%s\n, string)` printed the whole thing.